# A better way to write python closures?

Tags: python, closures

My question can be answered with a simple yes or no:

- Yes, `italic`'s "closure style" is the better way to write python 
  closures -- in other words -- `italic`'s "closure notation" won't break and
  has no caveats
- No, `italic`'s closures are problematic, `bold`'s "closure notation" is the 
  only way to go

Just in case, if somebody wonders "whats the matter", err why doesnt "he" 
use the standard closures - the standard form, it makes me to want to run away.

```
def example():

    # The standard X_x closure...
    #
    def bold(predecessor):
        def successor():
            return "<bold/>" + predecessor() + "</bold>"
        return successor

    # ...this looks sooo much better ^.^
    #
    def italic(predecessor):
        x = predecessor
        def successor():
            return "<italic/>" + x() + "</italic>"
        return successor

    def underline(predecessor):
        x = predecessor
        def successor():
            return "<underline/>" + x() + "</underline>"
        return successor

    @italic
    @bold
    @underline
    def trademark():
        return "This trademark cant be changed."

    print(trademark())
    #example() prints <italic/><bold/><underline/>This trademark cant be changed.</underline></bold</italic>
```

Comment: I suspect there's a real question up there, but I got bored reading your rant and gave up. What is it you want to know, guy?

Comment: You will probably get better and more polite responses if you just stick to the facts and not get bogged down with editorial comments. Just sayin'.

Comment: I haven't a clue why the cases you refer to are different.  Other than assigning a superfluous temporary variable (which isn't very costly) they are identical.

Comment: `"<italic/>" + x() + "</italic>"` is some strange-looking XML...

Comment: More importantly, `x` and `predecessor` are both in the local scope of `italic`, and therefore will be treated exactly the same when generating the `closure` for `successor`. How could it possibly be otherwise?

Comment: Also, do you not know how to examine this yourself by printing out the members of each function and its `__code__` member (see the [`inspect` docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/inspect.html) for a handy chart of all of the special attributes), disassembling the bytecode with [`dis.dis`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/dis.html), etc.? It takes only a moment to discover that the two versions are doing exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can do:

```
def italic(predecessor):
    x = predecessor
    def successor():
        return "<italic/>" + x() + "</italic>"
    return successor
```

Just like you can do:

```
def italic(predecessor):
    x = predecessor
    x2 = x
    def successor():
        return "<italic/>" + x2() + "</italic>"
    return successor
```

or

```
def italic(predecessor):
    x = predecessor
    x2 = x
    x3 = x2
    def successor():
        return "<italic/>" + x3() + "</italic>"
    return successor
```

But why would you want to?

---

The best way to write decorators is with [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
from functools import wraps

def italic(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated():
        return "<italic/>" + f() + "</italic>"
    return decorated
```

But if you really want to be different:

```
import functools

def italic(f):
    return functools.update_wrapper(lambda: "<italic/>" + f() + "</italic>", f)
```

Comment: Should probably point out that building strings using `+` is an antipattern in Python.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski What? It's not. Now, accumulating a string via a very large or unbounded number of concatenations has performance problems and should be avoided, but `+` is **the** idiomatic way to concatenate strings.

Comment: Arguably, this could be done with less hassle using `str.format()`, but yes, `+` to join a few strings like this is legitimate.

Comment: @delnan:  The OP's example expands to `"<bold/>" + ("<italic/>" + ("<underline/>" + predecessor() + "</underline>") + "</italic>") + "</bold>"`.  I think that is excessive.  FWIW, I often use `+` to join a few values, so I'm not totally opposed to the concept.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: That's not a very good argument. Is `"<bold/>{}</bold>".format("<italic/>{}</italic>".format("<underline/>{}</underline>".format(predecessor())))` any better?

Comment: @Eric:  That indeed is not any better, but I'm not advocating for using `str.format()`.    I'm thinking something much more lazy.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: So it's not really that building strings using `+` is an antipattern (which I don't think is relevant here, as Lattyware explained), but that building HTML using strings is a bad idea (which I agree with)?

Comment: @abarnert:  Yes.  That's what I meant.  I put it badly.